# Aligning ImageView to right of the layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/groupname"
         android:paddingLeft="50px"
         android:textSize="16px"
         android:background="#FFFFFF"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:textStyle="normal"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="50px"/>
     <ImageView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="right"
             android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
             android:background="#ffffff" 
             android:src="@drawable/sort"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Rendering like this presently]
[image: I want to render like this]

Rendering is happening now like in first image but I wanted to render like in second image fully right aligned. any help would be useful.

Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Comment: The people who mentioned RelativeLayout as a solution pretty much have the right solution. Just telling us not working is not helping yourself or anyone.

Comment: @Maurice thanks, but for me the answer did not work out for RelativeLayout, that is what I replied.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/groupname"
         android:paddingLeft="50dp"
         android:textSize="16dp"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:textStyle="normal"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.9"
         android:background="@color/black"/>
     <ImageView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="right"
             android:background="#ffffff" 
             android:src="@drawable/checkin"
             android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Try this, hope this will help.

[image: Prview1]
[image]

Comment: This can also be done without the layout_weight on the imageview if the imageview has a fixed width. Just set the layout_weight on the textview with a value of 1.

Answer (score 32):

use android:layout_weight="1" for text view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#FFFFFF">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/groupname"
     android:paddingLeft="50px"
     android:textSize="16px"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:background="#FFFFFF"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:textStyle="normal"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="50px"/>
 <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="right"
         android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
         android:background="#ffffff" 
         android:src="@drawable/sort"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect solution !

Answer (score 14):

Use RelativeLayout as a parent layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/groupname"
              android:paddingLeft="50px"
              android:textSize="16px"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textStyle="normal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="50px"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ncc"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/groupname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingLeft="50px"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16px"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/groupname"
     android:paddingLeft="50px"
     android:textSize="16px"
     android:background="#FFFFFF"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:textStyle="normal"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="50px"/>
 <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="right"
         android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
         android:background="#ffffff"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
         android:src="@drawable/sort"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your ImageView you should add `android:scaleType="fitEnd"`

Answer (score 0):

Either use RelativeLayout and set property of TextView as follows:

```
layout_width=fill_parent
layout_height=wrap_content
left_of="@+id/imgView"
```

and to ImageView

```
layout_width=wrap_content
layout_height=wrap_content
alignparentright=true
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add such thing in xml... to the object you want align right...

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
android:layout_marginRight="..dp"
```

Comment: thanks but this wont be possible as how would you set density pixels for different screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use drawableRight attribut to take it very simple like this example:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="50px"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_favorite_gray"/>
```